# Purify build using scons

Tags: scons, google-developers-console

I need to do purify build using SCons. Normally in nmake we would do

```
Nmake install -purify_7.0.1.0-008
```

How to do the same in SCons? Do I need to add any change in SConstruct file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to prefix SHCC,CC, SHCXX, CXX, SHLINK, LINK with purify, and likely add the path to your purify binary to env['ENV']['PATH']

You'll need to do this anywhere (in the main SConstruct, all SConscripts, and if you have any code in site_scons) which creates an Environment() to use.

If you create one `Enviroment()` and that gets exported to your SConscripts where it's then `env.Clone()`'d, then you'd only have to change it in the initial `env=Environment()`

Here's an example (not tested):

```
env=Environment() # this is your existing code

for v in ['SHCC','CC','SHCXX','CXX','LINK','SHLINK']:
   orig_value = env.subst('$%s'%v)
   env['v'] = "purify "+ orig_value
   print("Changing $%s from :\n%s\nto:\n%s",v, orig_value, env['v'])
```